# Filling the layout of different size

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app I am adding some images. I am using dp for all the measurements. When I see test this in different sizes available in eclipse, I could see that it is shown different in different devices.

[image]

(see the lollipop is filled for different length).

Please let me know avoid this and to create a similar look-and-feel in all devices

Following is the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="15" 
android:orientation="vertical">  

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll0"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"  
    android:orientation="horizontal" > 

                <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"  
                android:orientation="vertical" > 

                    <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll1A" 
                    android:layout_weight="3" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                        <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imOption1"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="90dp" 
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/repeat" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll1B" 
                    android:layout_weight="3" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                        <ImageButton
                         android:id="@+id/imOption2"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="90dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" 
                         android:background="@drawable/repeat"/> 
                     </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll1C" 
                        android:layout_weight="3" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imOption3"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="90dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" 
                        android:background="@drawable/repeat"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout> 

                <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"  
                android:orientation="vertical" > 

                    <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll2A" 
                    android:layout_weight="3" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                        <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imOption4"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="90dp" 
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/repeat" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll2B" 
                    android:layout_weight="3" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                        <ImageButton
                         android:id="@+id/imOption5"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="90dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" 
                         android:background="@drawable/repeat"/> 
                     </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll2C" 
                        android:layout_weight="3" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imOption6"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="90dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" 
                        android:background="@drawable/repeat"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"  
                android:orientation="vertical" > 

                    <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll3A" 
                    android:layout_weight="3" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                        <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imOption7"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="90dp" 
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/repeat" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll3B" 
                    android:layout_weight="3" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                        <ImageButton
                         android:id="@+id/imOption8"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="90dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" 
                         android:background="@drawable/repeat"/> 
                     </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll3C" 
                        android:layout_weight="3" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imOption9"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="90dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" 
                        android:background="@drawable/repeat"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>  

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:weightSum="9"
                android:background="#FFFF99" 
                android:orientation="vertical" >  


             <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/ll4A"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical" >
                  <ImageView
                      android:id="@+id/ivDisplayArea"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
                      android:layout_gravity="center"
                      android:background="@drawable/repeat"/>
                   </LinearLayout>  
            </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="10"  
    android:orientation="horizontal"> 
             <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:background="#FF6633"
             android:text="Reward Account "
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/bReward1"
                 android:layout_width="30dp"
                 android:layout_height="30dp"
                 android:layout_gravity="center" 
                 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/lollipop" /> 

            <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/bReward2"
                 android:layout_width="30dp"
                 android:layout_height="30dp"
                 android:layout_gravity="center" 
                 android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/lollipop" /> 

            <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/bReward3"
                 android:layout_width="30dp"
                 android:layout_height="30dp"
                 android:layout_gravity="center" 
                 android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/lollipop" /> 

            <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/bReward4"
                 android:layout_width="30dp"
                 android:layout_height="30dp"
                 android:layout_gravity="center" 
                 android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/lollipop" /> 

            <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/bReward5"
                 android:layout_width="30dp"
                 android:layout_height="30dp"
                 android:layout_gravity="center" 
                 android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/lollipop" /> 

            <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/bReward6"
                 android:layout_width="30dp"
                 android:layout_height="30dp"
                 android:layout_gravity="center" 
                 android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/lollipop" /> 

            <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/bReward7"
                 android:layout_width="30dp"
                 android:layout_height="30dp"
                 android:layout_gravity="center" 
                 android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/lollipop" /> 

            <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/bReward8"
                 android:layout_width="30dp"
                 android:layout_height="30dp"
                 android:layout_gravity="center" 
                 android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/lollipop" /> 

            <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/bReward9"
                 android:layout_width="30dp"
                 android:layout_height="30dp"
                 android:layout_gravity="center" 
                 android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/lollipop" /> 

            <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/bReward10"
                 android:layout_width="30dp"
                 android:layout_height="30dp"
                 android:layout_gravity="center" 
                 android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/lollipop" /> 


</LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually correct behavior. Android works to make sure that the graphics items remain the same physical size regardless of screen density or screen size.

So, if you choose a button graphics image that is intended to be the size of a person's fingertip, that graphic should always be displayed the exact same physical size (i.e. size in inches) regardless of device characteristics.

---

If you prefer for your screen to be laid out in such a way that it looks the same on all devices, and is scaled so that the same look is bigger or smaller depending on screen size, then there are two ways to do this:

1. Instead of using *Density-Independent-Pixels* "`dip`" (or the equivalent "`dp`"), 
   use *Scale-Independent-Pixels* "`sip`" (or the equivalent "`sp`" - which scale 
   with system font size) or "`px`" (for
   *pixels*) to define your graphics component sizes.
2. Instead of adding all image to your "res/drawable" folder, add
   different size images with the same filenames to the various
   "res/drawable-ldpi", "res/drawable-mdpi", "res/drawable-hdpi", and
   "res/drawable-xhdpi" folders.

You will have to experiment with image sizes to get it right, but the ratios are defined here: [Launcher Icons: Size and Format](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size)

Comment: I prefer to have same view in all devices, meaning the screen should look similar in phone as well as tablet. Do we have any option for it.

Comment: Of course there are options for keeping the "look similar in phone as well as tablet". See my edits to the answer, above.